# DispatchQoS struct is missing on Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

OS: MacOS Mojave

Xcode: 10.1

VS for Mac: 7.7.3 (Visual Studio Community)

Xamarin.iOS: 12.2.1.13 (Visual Studio Community)

iOS Build > SDK version: 12.1

Aforementioned is my setup and I am unable to find `DispatchQoS` struct introduced in `iOS8`. I have tried searching for it in the Microsoft's official documentation as well but I couldn't find it there as well.

Is it really "missing" in Xamarin.iOS or am I missing on something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There have be series of recent PRs to fill in the missing Dispatch API so the odds are you do not have them unless you are building Xamarin.iOS from source.

- [[CoreFoundation] Implement missing dispatch API. Fixes #4606. #4967](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/pull/4967/files)

ObjC/Swift Dispatch.DispatchQoS = C# CoreFoundation.DispatchQualityOfService:

**Note:** Not sure why it was added to the `CoreFoundation` namespace vs. `Dispatch`

```cs
public enum DispatchQualityOfService : uint {
    UserInteractive = 0x21,
    UserInitiated   = 0x19,
    Default         = 0x15,
    Utility         = 0x11,
    Background      = 0x09,
    Unspecified     = 0x00,
}
```

- [[CoreFoundation, ObjCRuntime] Add DispatchBlock APIs, in particular those that surface QOS #5389](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/pull/5389)

Comment: I can see that DispatchQualityOfService was added on 17 Oct 2018 to the CoreFoundation namespace. When is a stable release containing this enum expected?

Comment: @Asad I have no idea  They have not even applied git tags to the latest releases so they are getting harder and harder to track (I have to look at the released version hash to get it the got commit sha .... I would ask on their gitter : https://gitter.im/xamarin/xamarin-macios

Comment: Thanks for giving me insights into what's going on. I will ask a question on the suggested gitter.